# What pest is attacking my poor Monstera Minima?

Tags: houseplants, pest-control, rhaphidophora

I have a beautiful *Monstera* minima that is being attacked by something.

what is weird - I don't see visible pests with my eyes. it looks however like something is sucking the leaves. the plan is dull and yellowing. and the underside of the leaves have a transparency that looks like something is sucking out the "juice" from the leaves but I can't see webs or anything powdery to think it's spider mites or lots of brown to think it's thrips.

Any advice is appreciated. I did spray it  with neem a while back once and rinsed if off after.
Oh today I found a brown bug on it - I have no idea what it was but it was bigger. I didn't get a picture of it. but I was wondering if it was feeding on something on the plant?

Pictures are below. Thank you in advance for any help with this!

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

[image]

EDIT / UPDATE!
Hi all - just thought i'd check back in with an update. I found another thread that i wish i could refind on Reddit of all places. Similar images same plant. The issue was water. I tend to let my plants really dry out and then i give them a heavy water. Well the monsteras get water logged and will attempt to get rid of water via the leaves. that is what the dark green color is. when i adjusted my watering schedule it went back to it's previous happy plant self.

I noticed my deliciousa will drip water from it's leaves when i give it a heavy watering. So this must be a monstera thing - not a pest issue! I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Did you inspect it very closely? Thrips could be very tiny early on, but still could cause big damage.

Comment: i did @BenceKaulics i can't find any visible thing on it. someone suggested that perhaps i gave it too much light and not enough watering consistency. it was under grow lights and it did dry out a lot. i'm just not sure. Maybe it could be thrips but i don't see those brown spots they leave. again i'm no pest  expert and  am relatively new to monsters just  starting growing them in the past year. but i have a house full of many plants that are healthy too so it's not a big infestation whatever it is! or maybe it's me :)

Comment: Post your edit as an answer please.